# Different log4j configuration for Sonar

Tags: java, maven, logging, sonarqube

Best wishes for the new year.

I have a question regarding the log4j configuration with sonar, especially with cobertura.

Let me explain you. I'm working on a big project with a lot of modules and unit tests.

Those tests can be launched by developer on their workstation, and we don't want the log4j configuration for those tests to be set to DEBUG (too much log in debug).

But we would like to set the log to debug with cobertura, because we use the "isDebugEnabled", so in the "code coverage" section those line are always set to not tested.

So is it possible to change the log4j configuration just for cobertura ?

We use sonar via maven for information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed the log4g file link in the maven sonar profile.